# Python staticmethod and dependency injection

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Can someone help me with a good explanation on why a staticmethod on python is useful for dependency injection?

I was seeing this great video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_kZDvwofHY and on 45m45s Thomas Wouters claim that staticmethods are useful for DI, but I can't grasp why.

...

After start to writing this post, and made some tests I think I got it.
An example:

```
class GreetPrint(object):

    def pp(self, param):
        print("Hello", param)


class User(object):

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

    def print_user(self):
        self.output(self.param)

    @staticmethod
    def output(msg):
        return print_dependency.pp(msg)


print_dependency = GreetPrint()

a = User("Guido")
a.print_user()
```

This is a better approach (at least in Python) than injecting through the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is where the client provides something the caller needs on to the caller.

In you're example it looks like the dependency being configured is the output method, in this case `GreetPrint`

In the example provided there is a tight coupling between the `User` and the output method `GreetPrint`.  Imagine if we were required to change the way `User` was outputted.  There is a tight coupling to the print dependency floating in global scope.  Different outputters could be applied to users through inheritance but then a large inheritance graph begins to develop and the [benefits of dependency injection and composition are lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

In this case the client isn't providing the `User` with the output method, the user only has a single output method `GreetPrint`, and it cannot be configured by the client.

The way you have it setup now looks considerably harder to work with than injecting the outputter into the constructor.

Dependency injection can be established by programming to an interface which removes the coupling of the target on its dependency.  I feel like the dependency in this case the the output method.

---

Should the user be responsible for outputting itself?  Or should the user be acted upon by the out putter?  Are there other types of objects besides users the program has to output?